# Find characters after second to last position of hyphen in string using T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

I have a column in my database that has a field that looks like XYZ-13-1234-12345-6789-1

I would like to return the string XY-6789-1 so I am eliminating 13-1234-12345.

I know how to use SUBSTRING to get the first characters and I have the last characters using SUBSTRING(RTRIM(myString), LEN(myString), 1).

I tried using REVERSE but it returns the numbers backwards so instead of getting 6789 I get 9876 and that won't work.

Here is what I have figured out so far....it works perfectly but it looks terrible!

```
SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(myString)), 1, 2) + '-' + REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(LTRIM(RTRIM(myString))), (CONVERT(INT, CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(LTRIM(RTRIM(myString))))) + 1), CONVERT(INT, CHARINDEX('-', (SUBSTRING(REVERSE(LTRIM(RTRIM(myString))), (CONVERT(INT, CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(LTRIM(RTRIM(myString))))) + 1), LEN(myString))))) - 1)) + '-' + SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(myString)), LEN(myString), 1) AS NewColumnFormat
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the function from [SQL Server Central](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/Miscellaneous/30497/). Using the function `CHARINDEX2` would allow you to solve it using:

```
SELECT LEFT('XYZ-13-1234-12345-6789-1', dbo.CHARINDEX2('-','XYZ-13-1234-12345-6789-1', 1)) + RIGHT('XYZ-13-1234-12345-6789-1', dbo.CHARINDEX2('-', REVERSE('XYZ-13-1234-12345-6789-1'), 2) - 1)
```

Still not that great, but might easier to read than your original solution.

Comment: Hi Jody, part of the problem is that I won't always have a fixed amount in the first or last section. I only want 'XY' even if there is 'XYZABC' in one string and 'XY' in another. It's nasty but I figured it out....see above.

Comment: I updated my Original answer. You might find that solution a bitter less complex.